# How does /b work in regular expression in R?

Tags: r, regex

```
grepl(“o\b”, “hello”)
```

The expression above gives me “False”. From what I understand, “o\b” is supposed to look for “o” at the end of a word. Is this not supported in R?

Comment: In R, you need to use double "\\". Try `grepl("o\\b", "hello")`